# How to find aggregate value for rows in a table in different range of values in Bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a bigquery table in format company_id, date, sales_amount. sales_amount is a FLOAT64 column which value can vary from 0 to 1 Billion. I need to find the first date for every company_id a particular sales_amount range hit for the first time.

What I have written so far is for each range a with clause is used for example :

```
With A as (
SELECT company_id, min(date) breakDate
FROM <table>
WHERE sales_amount >= 100000 and sales_amount < 500000
GROUP BY company_id
),
B as (
SELECT company_id, min(date) breakDate
FROM <table>
WHERE sales_amount >= 500000 and sales_amount < 1000000
GROUP BY company_id
),
AllUnion AS (
SELECT * FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
USING(company_id)
WHERE B.breakDate > A.breakDate OR B.company_id is NULL

UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM B
)
```

So when a new range is added I have to add a new With section and in the last a big union section to merge all the break events. In the merge time I will make sure that if Higher order events happend first then lower order events are filtered out. For example in this case a company made more than 500K sales in Jan (First time) and their sales went down and hit 120K in Feb. Only 500K sales event will be returned Feb event will be filtered out

I have to do it for different tables and might have more events, I am wondering is there a smart way to write this query in bigquery ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bucketize to make `sales_amount` within a bucket have same bucket id. And then by group-by `company_id` and `bucket_id`, you are able to get `MIN(date)` of each bucket.

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/mathematical_functions#range_bucket

```sql
SELECT company_id, MIN(date) AS breakDate 
  FROM <table>
 WHERE sales_amount >= 100000 
 GROUP BY company_id, RANGE_BUCKET(sales_amount, [100000, 500000, 1000000]);
```

Example:

```sql
WITH sales AS (
  SELECT 'c1' AS company_id, '2022-05-01' AS date, 99999 AS sales_amount
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c1' AS company_id, '2022-05-02' AS date, 100000 AS sales_amount
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c1' AS company_id, '2022-05-03' AS date, 499999 AS sales_amount
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c1' AS company_id, '2022-05-04' AS date, 500000 AS sales_amount
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c1' AS company_id, '2022-05-05' AS date, 1100000 AS sales_amount
)  
SELECT company_id, 
       buckets[SAFE_OFFSET(RANGE_BUCKET(sales_amount, buckets) - 1)] AS bucket_id,
       ARRAY_AGG(sales_amount ORDER BY date)[OFFSET(0)] AS sales_amount,
       MIN(date) AS breakDate
  FROM sales, UNNEST([STRUCT([100000, 500000, 1000000] AS buckets)])
 WHERE sales_amount >= 100000 
 GROUP BY company_id, bucket_id
;
```

output:

[image]

example 2 :

```sql
WITH sales AS (
  SELECT 'c1' AS company_id, '2022-05-01' AS date, 99999 AS sales_amount
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c1' AS company_id, '2022-05-02' AS date, 100000 AS sales_amount
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c1' AS company_id, '2022-05-03' AS date, 499999 AS sales_amount
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c1' AS company_id, '2022-05-05' AS date, 1100000 AS sales_amount
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c1' AS company_id, '2022-05-07' AS date, 500000 AS sales_amount
),
bucketized_sales AS (
  SELECT company_id, 
         buckets[SAFE_OFFSET(RANGE_BUCKET(sales_amount, buckets) - 1)] AS bucket_id,
         ARRAY_AGG(sales_amount ORDER BY date)[OFFSET(0)] AS sales_amount,
         MIN(date) AS breakDate
    FROM sales, UNNEST([STRUCT([100000, 500000, 1000000] AS buckets)])
   WHERE sales_amount >= 100000 
   GROUP BY company_id, bucket_id
)
SELECT *, MAX(bucket_id) OVER (PARTITION BY company_id ORDER BY breakDate ROWS  BETWEEN  UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)  factor
  FROM bucketized_sales 
 WHERE TRUE QUALIFY bucket_id > factor OR factor IS NULL
 ORDER BY breakDate
;
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way I could add the bucket info to the select query to understand which bucket it is ?
Also filter out lower order events coming after higher order. Ex company hitting 500K sales first and then sales going down and hitting 100K in the next month. So in this case filtering out the 100K events.

Comment: I've updated the query to display the bucket info for your first question.

Comment: hey thanks, it works perfect for me. Only thing now I am wondering is earlier I was left joining with the "with statements" and filtering out low sales amount events happening after hight sales amount events.

Comment: For your second question, I've assumed gross sales which increase over time. If you're considering net sales, you may need another approach to get the result you want.

Comment: sales is like that particular day sales. It is not cumulative.

Comment: Do you want to display only 1M bucket_id in my answer ?  If so, adding `ORDER BY bucket_id DESC LIMIT 1` would be enough.

Comment: I mean for me each of these sales events are like milestones. So company with your example company hit 100k sales in a day in May 2nd and 500 k sales on May 4th and 1 m sales on May 5th. This is the exactly the output I need for the example. But consider a case where there is no 100k and 499k entry on May 2 and 3rd  but in May 12th.. then the output rows will include 100k event with date May 12. But 500k sales happened before that so no point in showing the 100 k event so I want to filter it out.

Comment: I see. If I understood correctly, additional sample in my answer will be what you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245143/discussion-between-ted-and-jaytiger).

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot for your answers, Now all the things I have done using "With clauses" have implemented here..